# Accessing more properties of Local Security Policy with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to modify any property that is in secpol.msc > Security settings > Account Policies. Microsoft unfortunately only gives support for a few of them, so there are still properties that I can't access.

For the Account Policies for example, only the following are aviable to change via `net accounts`

```perl
NET ACCOUNTS  
[/FORCELOGOFF:{minutes | NO}]  
[/MINPWLEN:length]  
[/MAXPWAGE:{days | UNLIMITED}]  
[/MINPWAGE:days]  
[/UNIQUEPW:number] [/DOMAIN]
```

Is there any way to access and modify other properties?

I have looked into other questions that have been previously asked and answered, but most of them are outdated or associated with code that is literally unreadable and very hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Typically how this is done is to run secedit.exe and import the value(s) you want to implement or change from an .inf file. A more sophisticated solution would use PowerShell Desired State Configuration (DSC).

```
secedit.exe /import /db "C:\Windows\security\database\secedit.sdb" /cfg "C:\Windows\Temp\seceditsettings.inf" /areas SECURITYPOLICY /log "C:\Windows\Temp\seceditsettings.log"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/secedit-import

Quickstart: Convert Group Policy into DSC
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/quickstarts/gpo-quickstart?view=dsc-1.1